# call function multiple times using different values

Tags: postgresql, function

I have a postgres function which takes an integer, like this:

```
select public.delete_entry(value);
```

How can I call this multiple times passing different values? I have a list of 280 values, so I need to execute this 280 times, I could just go one by one and execute the function each time but I bet there's a better way

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `values()` clause to provide the input parameters:

```
select delete_entry(v.id)
from (
  values (42), (100), (20), (13)
) as v(id);
```

If the values are consecutive, you can use `generate_series()`

```
select delete_entry(v.id)
from generate_series(1,280) as v(id);
```

If the IDs are already in a table, then just select from that table:

```
select delete_entry(the_column)
from the_table;
```

Comment: I have these on a table, just one column with all the ids I need

Comment: Then it's even simpler: select public.delete_entry(column_name) from table_name